# Get the total with jQuery increment and decrement

Tags: jquery, html

jquery

```js
$('.extra').on('change', function(){
    $(this).closest('label').find('.icon').toggle($(this).prop('checked')); 
});

var check = [];
var extra1=0, extra2=0, extra3=0;

$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
    var checked = 0;
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
        checked = 1;
    }
    
    var check = $(this).val();
    if(check==='checkbox1'){
        extra1 = 10;    
    }
    
    if(check==='checkbox2') {
        extra2= 20;
        let valuea=$('input[name="increment"]').val();
        $(".inc").click(function() {
            valuea++;
            $('input[name="increment"]').val(valuea);
            $('#spa').text(valuea);    
            extra2=extra2*valuea;
            console.log(extra2);            
        });
        
        $(".dec").click(function() {
            if(valuea > 1){
                valuea--;
                $('input[name="increment"]').val(valuea);
                $('#spa').text(valuea);
            }
            else{
                $('.dec').attr("disabled","disabled");
            }
        });    
    
    }
    
    if(check==='checkbox3'){
        extra3 = 30;    
    }
    
    totalCost = extra1 + extra2 + extra3;
    $('#cost').text(totalCost);
});
```

```css
label{
 display: block;
     margin: 0 0 5px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 font-size: 15px;
 width: 180px;
 height: 40px;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
   }
input[type="text"]{
 border:none;
 width:20px;
}
.icon{
 float:right;
 width:10%;
 display:none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="extra" class="extra" value="checkbox1"/>checkbox1
</label>
<label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="extra1" class="extra" value="checkbox2"/>checkbox2
 <div class="icon" style="margin-top: -7;"> 
  <a class="inc" href="#">+</a>
  <input type="hidden" name="increment" value="1"/>
  <span id="spa" value="1">1</span>
  <a class="dec" href="#">-</a>
 </div>
</label>
<label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="extra2" class="extra" value="checkbox3"/>checkbox3
</label> 
<span id="cost"></span>
```

---

In output I want to calculate the total result of **extras**. I need the total amount when the user will increment or decrement the value of the checkbox2. how I will get it if there is any mistake then I am sorry new on the stackoverflow, thak you in advance.
Now the output of checkbox2 is **20** if I will increment it it become **40** if I again do increment then it gives **120** expect of **60**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puneet,
I modified many things in your code to make it clearer and simplier.

Here is a working example of what I "think" you try to do…
Comment me if I'm wrong !

```js
$('.extras').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('label').find('.icons').toggle($(this).prop('checked'));
  update_extras();
});

function change_val(element, value) {
  var extra = $(element).closest('label').find('.extras').attr("id");
  var nb = parseInt($("#" + extra).attr("nb")) + value;
  if (nb > 0) {
    $("#" + extra).attr("nb", nb);
    $("#" + extra).next("span").html("(" + nb + ")");
    update_extras();
  }
  return;
}

function update_extras() {
  var total = 0;
  // For each "extras" class element
  $(".extras").each(function(index) {
    var extra = 0;
    var id = "#extra" + (index + 1);
    // If checked, add nb * val to total
    if ($(id).is(":checked")) {
      extra = $(id).attr("nb") * $(id).attr("val");
      total = total + extra;
    }
  });
  $('#cost').text(total);
  return;
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border: none;
  width: 20px;
}

.icons {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="extra1" class="extras" nb="1" val="10"/>checkbox1 <span>(1)</span>
  <div class="icons">
    <a class="inc" onclick="change_val(this, 1);" href="#">[ + ]</a><br />
    <a class="dec" onclick="change_val(this, -1);" href="#">[ - ]</a>
  </div>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="extra2" class="extras" nb="1" val="20"/>checkbox2 <span>(1)</span>
  <div class="icons"> 
    <a class="inc" onclick="change_val(this, 1);" href="#">[ + ]</a><br />
    <a class="dec" onclick="change_val(this, -1);" href="#">[ - ]</a>
  </div>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="extra3" class="extras" nb="1" val="30"/>checkbox3 <span>(1)</span>
  <div class="icons"> 
    <a class="inc" onclick="change_val(this, 1);" href="#">[ + ]</a><br />
    <a class="dec" onclick="change_val(this, -1);" href="#">[ - ]</a>
  </div>
</label>
<span id="cost"></span>
```

EDIT: Now I modified almost all the JS code after your comments, Puneet.
Now the [+] and [-] will work if you copy/paste and add other checkboxes. But make sure to change the `id`s.
I used attributes `nb` for the increment/decrement value and `val` for the "cost" of each checkbox.
Note that you could choose a different increment or decrement.
Hope it helps, and tell me what you think about it !

Comment: if there are two or more checkbox like that then this code will works?? @takitisy

Comment: When you say 2 or more like "that", which one are you talking about ? The code may need to be adapted, but I don't see why it wouldn't work. Is that what you were trying to achieve ?

Comment: yeah but in main coding i have $ checkboxes like the checkbox2(incremented decremented checkboxes) does it work for them

Comment: I think I understand what you want.  I am goint to edit my answer and propose you something nice.

Comment: @Puneet Is that the way you wanted it ?

Comment: everything is alright but I have an doubt. @takitisy

Comment: doubt is that the values in the checkboxes are assigned dynamically @takitIsy

Comment: When you say dynamically… Are the values of the checkboxes assigned by the "server" or can it be assigned by the user ?  Do you need any more help or I consider it's closed ? :)

Comment: you can consider it's  closed :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Punnet you are just multiplying value of extra2 to the number and storing it to extra2 only. just change the variable extra2. So initially extra2 is 20 and value is 1 so it become 20 and the you change value to 2 become 40 and then 3 become 40*3 120.

```
You have write
extra2 = extra2*valuea // 20*2 extra2 become 40 then extra2*3 i.e 40*3 become 120 instead of 60 

Change extra2 = extra2*valuea this to 
extra3 = extra2*valuea // 20*2 extra2 remains 20 then 20*3 will become 60
```

Below is the code snippet

```js
$('.extra').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('label').find('.icon').toggle($(this).prop('checked')); 
});
var check = [];
var extra1=0, extra2=0, extra3=0;
  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
    var checked = 0;
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
          checked = 1;
     }       
    var check = $(this).val();
    if(check==='checkbox1'){
         extra1 = 10; 
   }
    if(check==='checkbox2'){
       extra2= 20;
    let valuea=$('input[name="increment"]').val();
    $(".inc").click(function() {
     valuea++;
    $('input[name="increment"]').val(valuea);
 $('#spa').text(valuea); 
 extra3=extra2*valuea;
 console.log(extra3);   
 });
 $(".dec").click(function() {
  if(valuea > 1){
  valuea--;
 $('input[name="increment"]').val(valuea);
 $('#spa').text(valuea);
 }
 else{
 $('.dec').attr("disabled","disabled");
   }
 }); 
 }
   if(check==='checkbox3'){
         extra3 = 30; 
 } 
 totalCost=extra1+extra2+extra3;
  $('#cost').text(totalCost);
     });
```

```css
label{
 display: block;
     margin: 0 0 5px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 font-size: 15px;
 width: 180px;
 height: 40px;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
   }
input[type="text"]{
 border:none;
 width:20px;
}
.icon{
 float:right;
 width:10%;
 display:none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="extra" class="extra" value="checkbox1"/>checkbox1
</label>
<label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="extra1" class="extra" value="checkbox2"/>checkbox2
 <div class="icon" style="margin-top: -7;"> 
  <a class="inc" href="#">+</a>
  <input type="hidden" name="increment" value="1"/>
  <span id="spa" value="1">1</span>
  <a class="dec" href="#">-</a>
 </div>
</label>
<label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="extra2" class="extra" value="checkbox3"/>checkbox3
</label> 
<span id="cost"></span>
```

Comment: it cannot show the output in `id="cost"` i want to calculate the total amount. @rupal thanks for replying i am calculating it from two days. but not success

Comment: @Puneet actually u have asked regarding that value of extra2. wait  let me check

Comment: @Puneet , you are only calculating value on change event not when increment and decrement is clicked, so calculate value in that event also.

Answer (score 0):

In calculation you have to change the logic. your initiating extra2 = 20 then multiply it with increment count and assign that to same extra2 variable. for second increment extra2 will be result of previous.

```
   $('input[name="increment"]').val(valuea);
    $('#spa').text(valuea); 
    extra21=extra2*valuea;
    console.log(extra21);           
    });
    $(".dec").click(function() {
     if(valuea > 1){
        valuea--;
    $('input[name="increment"]').val(valuea);
    $('#spa').text(valuea);
    }
    else{
    $('.dec').attr("disabled","disabled");
         }
    }); 
    }
```

Comment: thank Your for replying but i want to calculate the total amount. @prasannaputtaswamy

Comment: while calculating cost add extra23 instead of extra2 that will give you proper result.